# Query JArray using SelectTokens and a contains regex

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to write a method that will take the following JSON structure below and return the path proerty for all of these where path contains a string. So in this case, if I called GetPath(json, "User1") I would like to get ["User1\path1", "User1\path2"]

```
[  
   {  
      "id":90BCV,
      "name":"Path 1",
      "path":"User1\\path 1"
   },
   {  
      "id":90BC,
      "name":"Path 2",
      "path":"User1\\path 2"
   },
   {  
      "id":91AB,
      "name":"Path 3",
      "path":"User2\\path 3"
   }
]

    public static List<string> GetPath(string json, string key)
       {
           JArray reader = JArray.Parse(json);

           List<JToken> paths = reader.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.path=~@'" + key + "')]").ToList();
           List<string> returnList = new List<string>();

           foreach (JToken path in paths)
           {
                returnList.Add((string)path["path"]);
           }

                return returnList;
}
```

I have tried multiple different regex approaches but I just can not seem to get this query right. Most of the times I just end up getting an empty list or an invalid regex error.

Comment: I think, I have ran into the same issue. JsonPath doesn't support expressions to the top level array (please correct me if I'm wrong). You need to add an extra root node and make your array its content.

Comment: Do you need to put quotes around the `id` values?

Comment: @alans sorry that was a typo on my part. There are quotes around it. This is more for testing purposes. The JSON structure parses fine, I am just having trouble querying it. Will update the quesiton

Comment: @alans actually looking at the response there are no quotes around this value.. would that matter? id is not even used in the query, just path

Comment: @Tree55Topz Well, without the quotes, my parser is throwing out error with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to go with this approach. I would rather use .ToString() and then use .Contains inside the foreach loop.

```
JArray reader = JArray.Parse(json);
List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
foreach(var token in reader){
    string path = token["path"].ToString();
    if(path.Contains(key)){
        returnList.Add(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think the simpler approach is best here.. No need to use regex. Will go with something like this. Thanks!

Comment: just bear in mind, that for really large arrays JPath should be much faster

Answer (score 2):

That works

```
    static string json = @"
[  
   {  
      ""id"":""90BCV"",
      ""name"":""Path 1"",
      ""path"":""User1\\path 1""
   },
   {  
      ""id"":""90BC"",
      ""name"":""Path 2"",
      ""path"":""User1path 2""
   },
   {  
      ""id"":""91AB"",
      ""name"":""Path 3"",
      ""path"":""User2\\path 3""
   }
]
";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string key = "User2\\\\path 3";

      JArray reader = JArray.Parse(json);

      List<JToken> paths = reader.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.path=='" + key + "')]").ToList();

    }
```

few thing are there
- ==, not just =, cause JPath uses in-code compiler, so you follow C# convension.
- for the same reason, it you need \\ to represent \

Answer (score 2):

By the way, if you really want to do Regular Expression way, you almost had it right:

```
List<JToken> paths = reader.SelectTokens("$.[?(@.path=~/^" + key + "$/)]").ToList();
```